# How do I insert missing rows and conduct math between multiple files?

Tags: python, unix, text

I have two files that contain two columns each. The first column is an integer. The second column is a linear coordinate. Not every coordinate is represented, and I would like to insert all coordinates that are missing. Below is an example from one file of my data:

```
  3 0
  1 10
  1 100
  2 1000
  1 1000002
  1 1000005
  1 1000006
```

For this example, coordinates 1-9, 11-99, etc are missing but need to be inserted, and need to be given a count of zero (0).

```
  3 0
  0 1
  0 2
  0 3
  0 4
  0 5
  0 6
  0 7
  0 8
  0 9
  1 10
  ........
```

With the full set of rows, I then need to add add (1) to every count (the first column). Finally, I would like to do a simple calculation (the ratio) between the corresponding rows of the first column in the two files. The ratio should be real numbers.

I'd like to be able to do this with Unix if possible, but am somewhat familiar with python scripting as well. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with Python 2.3 onwards.

I assumed that your file is space delimited.

If you want values past 1000006, you will need to change the value for `desired_range` .

```
import csv

desired_range = 1000007
reader = csv.reader(open('fill_range_data.txt'), delimiter=' ')

data_map = dict()
for row in reader:
    frequency = int(row[0])
    value = int(row[1])

    data_map[value] = frequency

for i in range(desired_range):
    if i in data_map:
        print data_map[i], i
    else:
        print 0, i
```